# Java: Display "Europe/Stockholm" time whatever my locale is

Tags: java, android

I ma trying to get the output time of "Europe/Stockholm" timezone whatever my computer local is (I have currently got GMT 0 on my laptop).

```
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Stockholm");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

        Date date = new Date();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.setTimeZone(tz);
        long curSeconds = (cal.getTimeInMillis()/(long)1000);
        Log.v("Karl","new Date() "+cal.getTime());
```

But this still outputs:

```
        new Date() Wed Mar 04 17:33:53 GMT+00:00 2015
```

I would like it to display the timezone of "Europe/Stockholm" as said!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `cal.getTime()` you get `java.util.Date`. `java.util.Date` has no time zone - it is just a point in timeline, without location. (I mean you lost your calendar timezone when you `cal.getTime()`)

`java.util.Date.toString()` displays date in host timezone (`Timezone.getDefault()`)

That was a theory. Practice:

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
  df.setTimeZone(tz);
  System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

You will get

```
Wed Mar 04 22:01:53 CET 2015
```